# React Native, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_configProvider.remoteModuleConfig')

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

Create a react-native project using `create-react-native-app` and ejected without any change. After that, running the command `yarn run android` generates a proper bundle and launches the app on my phone connected via USB. However a red screen with the message `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_configProvider.remoteModuleConfig')` appears for a few seconds, before the app crashes.

`cat package.json`

```
{
  "name": "rn-expo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "^0.3.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.42.3"
  }
}
```

Tried to run the command with Gradle 3.4.1 and Gradle 2.14.1.

The phone was a Google Pixel 7.1.1. Also tried with Genymotion, emulating Nexus 5X 6.0.0 (with emulator, the red screen persists).

Full error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_configProvider.remoteModuleConfig') (http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3547)

http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3547:56
get@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3934:12
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:3369:32
loadModuleImplementation@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:127:8
guardedLoadModule@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:70:32
_require@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:54:18
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:27365:26
loadModuleImplementation@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:127:8
guardedLoadModule@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:70:32
_require@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:54:18
setUpDevTools@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:22968:26
http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:22997:14
loadModuleImplementation@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:127:8
guardedLoadModule@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:63:37
_require@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:54:18
global code@http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:85271:9
```

[RN app crash red screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfkwI.png)

Comment: The problem was solved by just upgrading my OS version :)

Comment: Which OS? I am having same issue

Comment: Upgraded Mac OS X from Yosemite to Sierra.

Comment: The error was with mainBundle Created. I recreated the main bundle and error was solved.